# Bootstrap menu not responsive on smart phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I used for my site [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ekony) type of menu. Everything went fine until I tested it on my smart phone. The menu is not responsive. But on my laptop if I resize the browser's window, it is responsive. Any ideea why does this happen?
I used Visual Studio and different types of Bootstrap (3.3.0, 3.3.2 and 3.3.7)

Comment: Make sure this is the HTML HEAD.. 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: If you tell me that this duplicate isn't the problem I will reopen.